# Can't Get CiviCRM BuildKit files From Repository

Tags: drupal

Unable to get CiviCRM buildkit files.

I am running:

- OS:           Linux   -  Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
- WebServer:    Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)   built:   2018-04-25T11:38:24
- Database      MYSQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22
- Language:     PHP   -  Version 7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
- Language:     Node.js  - v10.5.0
- VCS:          git version 2.17.1

Executed command below as advised at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/

```
curl -Ls https://civicrm.org/get-buildkit.sh | bash -s -- --full --dir ~/buildkit
```

Got the results below.

```
root@joe-Meerkat:/home/joe# curl -Ls https://civicrm.org/get-buildkit.sh | bash -s -- --full --dir ~/buildkit
Detected Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Task: acl git wget unzip zip mysql-server mysql-client php7.2-cli php7.2-imap php7.2-ldap php7.2-curl php7.2-mysql php7.2-intl php7.2-gd php7.2-dev php7.2-bcmath php7.2-mbstring php7.2-soap php7.2-zip php7.2-xml apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.2 nodejs npm php-pear libmcrypt-dev libreadline-dev

Warning: This system will not support php-mysql extension

Run automated installation? [Y/n] y
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
-
-
-

Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease

Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu bionic 
Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is 
therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
root@joe-Meerkat:/home/joe#
```

Does anyone know the cause of this and what can be done?

joseph.c.mansigian@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

At that point in the install script, it is attempting to run `sudo apt-get -y install` for a bunch of packages.

It looks like you have added a ppa for midori but that does not have a bionic release yet.  You can run `sudo add-apt-repository -r -u ppa:midori/ppa` or find the entry for midori in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and comment it out and run `sudo apt update`

Once you can get `sudo apt-get -y install` to run cleanly on some (any) package, try again with the `get-buildkit.sh` script.

Note also that bionic comes with php 7.2 which is marked as 'not yet tested' in https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#php-version so unless you are only interested in the very latest releases and debugging 7.2 issues, you probably want php 7.1 (see eg https://tecadmin.net/install-php-7-on-ubuntu/).  However, if you do that you'll need to install the 7.1 version of the php extensions.  Look at the php7.1-* list in the 'do_system_artful' function of `get-buildkit.sh`

Comment: Note that you may need to deal with the 'Warning: This system will not support php-mysql extension'